# Troubleshooting radeon drivers in Debian vs. Trisquel vs. Ubuntu

Tags: debian, drivers, graphics, radeon, trisquel

Using an ATI 5770 on a 2560x1440 monitor. When I first install Ubuntu 14.04 I'm given the full 2560x1440 resolution. It says it's using the free drivers and that closed source ones are available. In Debian 8 and Trisquel 7 however I get 1920x1440.

Following this https://wiki.debian.org/AtiHowTo I was able to get the full 2560x1440 in Debian. This line ". . . install the open source display driver packages, DRI modules (for 3D acceleration) and driver firmware/microcode" confuses me though. Is it using parts of the non-free (DRI?) for 3D then open source for 2D? Is this what Ubuntu does by default?

Either way I switched to Trisquel because I didn't like Debian. And I'm not sure how to mimic what's written there for this distro, or if I even should.